# "Someone else than me" correct analogy?

Tags: analogy, connected-speech

Here's an example sentence:

I couldn't expect you loved someone else than me.

Or something like that, you get the meaning.

I tried googling "Someone else of me", "Someone else than me". None of the above are correct and/or used.

How do I highlight that that someone is not ME? That I expected that to be me but it turned out it was someone else, but not me?

I've just found out "but not me" would be a good option, however to me it isn't connected to the word "else" as I want it to.

"Someone who differs from me" - you see, differs is 100 percent connected to the "who" word. Whereas "Someone, but who isn't me" is more connected to the "Someone word".

I want to know your opinion on this.

The most beautiful and clear and connected to the "else" word construction there is, what's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Someone other than me' works fine in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

***[Other than](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/other-than)*** is the idiomatic expression you need to use to convey the meaning:

> You use other than after a negative statement to say that the person, item, or thing that follows is the only exception to the statement.
>
> - *She makes no reference to any feminist work other than her own.
>     The journey by road to Wolverhampton is not recommended to anyone other than the most experienced cyclist.*

(Collins Dictionary)